# MySQL New Column at SELECT added, but the value isn't increasing, Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

It is a so long SELECT, so i wouldn't show the whole code but the problem is here:

```
SET @idcounter=0;
SET @SQL = CONCAT('
CREATE TABLE temp_',CONCAT(InvNum),CONCAT('(
SELECT
    '),CONCAT(@idcounter:=@idcounter+1),CONCAT(' as ID,
/* Show Output columns */
/*
```

Instead of 1, 2, 3, etc. values, it only gives 1's everywhere.
So i tried an other solution.

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('SET ',CONCAT(@idcounter=0),CONCAT(';
CREATE TABLE temp_',CONCAT(InvNum),CONCAT('(
SELECT
    '),CONCAT(@idcounter:=@idcounter+1),CONCAT(' as ID,
/* Show Output columns */
/*
```

But this gives an error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1   0.015 sec

To be honest, i have no more idea what to do with this problem. 
What am i missing?

The "InvNum" is a  working param, that's can't be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the use of

```
CONCAT('(SELECT '), CONCAT(@idcounter:=@idcounter+1)
```

This causes the `SELECT` statement to insert the `@idcounter` variable value at the time of execution as opposed to your desired per `SELECT` row.

Which sets `@SQL` as:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_123 
SELECT 1 as ID
```

You just need to remove the redundant`CONCAT()` calls.

```
SET @idcounter=0;
SET @SQL=CONCAT('
CREATE TABLE temp_',InvNum, '
SELECT @idcounter:=@idcounter+1 as ID')
```

Which sets `@SQL` as:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_123 
SELECT @idcounter:=@idcounter+1 as ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very helpful, it works in this way